# What settings might have been used to get this photo with clear stars and long trails from car lights?

Tags: exposure, long-exposure, night, stars

[image]
<sup>[*Di ritorno dalla Val Gardena — alto adige*](https://guerrinistefano.com/2017/08/29/di-ritorno-dalla-val-gardena-trentino/), by [Stefano Guerrini](https://guerrinistefano.com)</sup>

I am assuming that the photographer used 400- 800 ISO along with the 15-20 seconds of shutter speed. But, If there is a long exposure then why I am not able to see the star trails where as car trails are there.

How can I achieve something like this? Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

This pic is composed of different pics shot with different settings and heavy post processing.

There is a demonstration of such a pic in youtube. I don't know whethere external links are allowed here.

Comment: They are alowed but after you get more reputation. :o)

Comment: What sort of different settings do you think were used in the different shots? What kinds of heavy post processing do you think were used?

Comment: @scottbb I can find about 4-5 pics here shot at different places. There may be more. The road, hill, sky, field are what I can find. Low shutter speed, astro photography setting and editing exposure, contrast, brightness, layering etc in Lightroom or PS.

Comment: The reason I ask is to encourage you to explain _in your answer_ what you're seeing. More flushed-out answers yield more upvotes, which is nice from an "internet points" viewpoint. But more importantly, better answers can turn mediocre questions into good questions, which increases the site's visibility, resulting in better questions and answers, which feeds back again...

Comment: @scottbb The depth of this answer is consistent with the enforcement of "don't post answers in the comments" moderation practices on this site. The recent "why was this answer flagged" meta-thread is probably also related. Yeah, I am a little torqued that my comment to the question here was moderated to the bit bucket within a few hours of having posted it under "don't use comments as answers". I didn't post it as answer, because I did not think it was a good answer, I doubted it was **correct enough** since it was off the top of my head. TANSTAAFL

Comment: @benrudgers I'm not quite sure where you're going with that, comparing the quality of an answer with the practice of asking people not to answer in comments. I don't see the connection. Better answers are for the good of everybody — the answerer (in "internet points", for what's that worth), the asker, the Photo.SE community (especially in terms of the SNR of the content of the site), and the SE company (in terms of their higher placement in searching, which corresponds to better ad rates).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than give specific settings, I'll try to describe the three (possibly two) different components of this photomontage. Being specific and accurate at the same time would be waaaay above my pay grade and frankly beyond my expertise.

To take long-exposure astrophotos of objects that are too faint to be seen, you will need a polar-aligned equatorial mounting that allows you to accurately track the stars during the exposure to compensate for the Earth's rotation. Any other kind of mount will rotate the view which is fine for viewing but not for astrophotography.

If you don't already have a telescope and mounting, and you want to seriously pursue astrophotography, you should consider getting a good German-equatorial mounting. Put it on a rock-solid tripod. You can get piggy-back camera mounts for a telescope, too.

A computerized drive for smooth tracking of the sky during the exposure is necessary for sharp results like the one shown.

The time exposure of the "moonlit" landscape is the second exposure melded with the sky. Notice the light tell-tale outline where the sky meets the tops of the rock outcropping. This exposure must be found, on location, by experiment.

Last is the hairpin-turn portion of the photograph. Looking at the light trails and the terrain, an estimate of the length of the exposure is within a guessable range. It is possible (and if you're lucky) that the time exposure of the road was also sufficient to pick up the moonlit landscape at the same time as the head/tail light trails for a two-part composite.

After the components are recorded, the images are stacked and masked with software such as PhotoShop (most likely), Gimp, Pixelmator, etc. to generate the composite image.